# How to perform click action on this particular button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, relative-locators

I was asked this question on interview. I need to perform click action on "open" button
which is opposite to "CLR-9194":

[image]

I told that with help of **index** I can perform action on that particular "open" button:

`findElement(By.xpath("//label[2]"))`

But he told me that I was **wrong**.

Comment: Your task was given in terms of the cell content, `CLR-9194`, so any solution not even containing a reference to that specified content, must be wrong. The visual appearance was given as an illustration, not an invitation to write code that only works if the page looks exactly like that.

Comment: Post the relevant html of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to locate the table row parent element based on the `CLR-9194` content and then to find the `open` button child element of that row.
So, if each table row is `td` element (it can be `tr`, I don't know, you did not share the XML) and the `open` element is "label" the XPath can be something like this:

```java
"//td[contains(.,'CLR-9194')]//label"
```

The Selenium code will be correspondingly something like:

```java
findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'CLR-9194')]//label"))
```

the XPath above can and should be made more precise. We need to see the XML for that.

Comment: What is that ``//label`` in your **Selenium** code?

Comment: The `open` button inside the row as mentioned by the OP.